# Find all string occurrences after a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Just need a little push here. I have a file with data like

```
xyz  buildinfo app_id="12345" asf
sfsdf buildinfo app_id="12346" wefwef
...
```

I need to get a string array with the number following **app_id=**. Below code gives me all matches and i am able to get the count( Regex.Matches(text, searchPattern).Count). But I need the actual items into an array.

```
 string searchPattern = @"app_id=(\d+)";
                var z = Regex.Matches(text, searchPattern);
```

Comment: `new Regex(searchPattern).Match(text).Captures` (or `.Groups`)

Comment: Do you absolutely need the Regex or you would equally go with string methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying you want the items (numbers) without the app_id part.  You want to use a [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
string text = @"xyz  buildinfo app_id=""12345"" asf sfsdf buildinfo app_id=""12346"" wefwef";
string searchPattern = @"(?<=app_id="")(\d+)";
var z = Regex.Matches(text, searchPattern)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(m => m.Value)
              .ToArray();
```

`(?<=app_id="")` will match the pattern, but not include it in the capture

Comment: This works just fine! But it picks strings like app_id=12345 . I just need the number. How can I change the RE. Or should i use a Replace on the Select

Comment: i see the problem. I was still using my same RE

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx).

Quoting it you can use this code:

```
  string pattern = @"app_id=(\d+)";
  string input = "xyz  buildinfo app_id="12345" asf sfsdf buildinfo app_id="12346" efwef";

  Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
  if (match.Success) {
     Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value);
     for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= match.Groups.Count - 1; ctr++) {
        Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
        int captureCtr = 0;
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[ctr].Captures) {
           Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", 
                             captureCtr, capture.Value);
           captureCtr += 1;                  
        }
     }
  }
```